# How can I create a Cascading Async Select using @atlaskit/select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, atlaskit

I started with React recently and I am trying to figure out how to create a Cascading Async Select (eg. Country > City) using [@atlaskit/select](https://atlassian.design/components/select/async-select/examples).

Following the doc I use the option `loadOptions` in the first Async Select (Country) and `onChange={({ label, value }) => handleCountryOptionChange(value)}` to call the API that returns the Cities. The cities are defined as `[cities, setCities] = useState(undefined)` and the second Async Select (City) has the `loadOptions = cities`. The Cities options are displayed right in the console whenever you click on a different Country but they are not rendered.

Any idea or example about how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are handling the fetch separately and loadOptions= expects a function so maybe try options=cities (instead of loadOptions) for your Cities select control.